# Регистрация на AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Ребята ,пожалуйста подкорректируйте код . Сделал вроде чтоб у каждого пользователя открывалась своя страничка под своим логином и паролем но почему-то не получается чтоб при вводе определенного пароля и логина переходило на страницу ,а при неверном вводе просто прочерки((

index.php

```
 <html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>титулка</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function myEvent(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ 
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
var val_x = "tech_user";
var val_y = "password";
xmlhttp.open("GET","connect.php?n111="+val_x+"&n222="+val_y,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>                                                  
</head>
<body> 
<p id="status"></p>
Ввести текст
<p>login <input id="n111" name="nm"></p>
<p>passw <input id="n222" name="nm"></p>
<input type="button" value="Передать данные" onclick="myEvent()" />
<br><br><br>
<div id="result1">0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

page.php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Пример веб-страницы</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Олег Копыча</h1>
  <!-- Комментарий -->
  <p>в работе</p>
  <p>отсутствие</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
    <?php
$log = ['tech_user'];
$pass= ['n222'];
if($_GET['n111']=="tech_user"){
    $y = ($_GET['n222']=="n222");
 echo header( "Location: page.php" );" (".$y.")";
    }
else{
    echo "--------";
}



?>
```

Comment: _подкорректируйте код_ - это когда написано,  99.9% кода, но можно улучшить. Вы же просите написать за вас 98.9%.

Comment: Эмм по моему код вы и не смотрели . У меня здесь большая часть написана , я просто не знаю как теперь сделать возможность записывать чтоб сравнивалось и тогда выводило или не выводило страницу .

Comment: Возможно. `echo` и `header` в одной строке это нонсенс. Если `header` отработал, а вам хочется добавить в `URL` параметры, то скорее `header( "Location: page.php?param=$y" );` как то так.

Comment: Возвращайте назад адрес страницы которую надо открыть, а получаемый ajax результат проверяйте на содержание только тире или там есть адрес, и перекидывайте пользователя средствами JS `location.href = ajaxResult;`

Comment: А разве нельзя как-то в var val_x = "tech_user";
var val_y = "password"; вставить ID  который относиться к полям ввода для логина и пароля , в моем случае это  n111  и n222

Comment: Я думал это можно сделать на много проще ,нет ?

Comment: То есть вы заранее знаете какая страница откроется? А что вам тогда мешает после запроса открывать её js'oм?

Comment: Насколько помню ajax ворачивает результат а не куда его отправили

Comment: И по факту, Ajax нужен что бы изменить страницу(или отправить что то) без перехода(и рефреша), если вам нужен переход зачем использовать Ajax?